# Issue while getting node properties

Tags: java, aem, jcr, jackrabbit

I am trying to get node properties in CQ. But I am not able to get the properties. Getting exception says it is not a relative path.

```
Session session;
Node root = session.getRootNode();
Node jcrContent = root.getNode("/content/moto/contact/jcr:content");
System.out.println("val:"+jcrContent.getProperty("jcr:title"));
```

> Exception occurred `Not a relative path:
>   /content/moto/contact/jcr:content`

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CQ5 you probably want to rely in the Sling API instead of the underlying JCR. You can use the ResourceResolver for this purpose:

```
Resource resource=resourceResolver.getResource("/your/resource");
ValueMap props= resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class)
String title= props.get("jcr:title");
```

The resource resolver is available always through a Sling request (slingRequest.getResourceResolver()). If you don't have a request available (like in a workflow), you can still get one, but it depends on your scenario

Comment: +1 for the use of ValueMap instead of JCR API in AEM/CQ5. Just an addition to the answer , make sure , the ResourceResolver coming from the Sling Request has "read" access to the node path i.e "/content/moto/contact/jcr:content" in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Node root = session.getRootNode();
Node jcrContent = root.getNode("content/moto/contact/jcr:content");
```

The [#getNode()](http://www.day.com/specs/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#getNode(java.lang.String)) expects a relative path, whereas you were providing an absolute path. Hence the error, `not a relative path`.